# What isn't this code inserting values into SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am writing an app for android. I need to read a txt file and write the data in an SQLite file. I have managed to complete all the code, but the part where it should insert the value into the database is not working. I have given the code below:

```
try{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, firstNumber); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, strfinal); // Contact Phone
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is not entering the value into the database and the database remains empty after the operation is completed. What is wrong with this? Thanks.
EDIT: Ok, here is the full code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // All Static variables
        // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "feedsmanager.sqlite";

        // Contacts table name
        private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "table_to_hold_all_values";

        // Contacts Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";//ctid
        private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";//feedname,address;feedname;address etc
        Context ctx;

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            ctx=context;
        }

        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            //Log.d("in onCreate","twitch1");
            String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT);";

            //Log.d("below createcontacts","twitch1");
            try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
            }catch(Exception e){Log.d("create went wrong: "+e,"twitch11");}
            //Log.d("below db.execsql","twitch1");
            populate(db);
    }

            void populate(SQLiteDatabase dbs){
            String line="";


            try{
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("feedtitlesandaddresses.txt");
            InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(iz);
            //SQLiteDatabase dbs = this.getWritableDatabase();
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                //Log.d("fcked here6","twitch1");
                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "<");

                String firstNumber="";
                String strfinal="";
                  firstNumber = (String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();
                  **//Calculations to give values to firstNumber and strfinal excluded

                  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                  values.put(KEY_NAME, firstNumber); // Contact Name
                  values.put(KEY_PH_NO, strfinal); // Contact Phone
                  // Inserting Row

                  dbs.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);}

                dbs.close();}catch(Exception e){Log.d("yeah error is"+e,"twitch12");}
        }}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in your logcat? Please post it.

Comment: @span No! I put it in a try catch block, no error!

Comment: @user2213396: show your `try/catch`

Comment: Well, do you get an exception then? What does the stack trace say? You should be able to catch a sql exception.

Comment: How do you know the database is empty?  Maybe the part of the code that reads the database is wrong.  If you're using the emulator, actually download the database and use sqlite3 to read it.

Comment: @dbDev Yes I downloaded it off the emulator, it's empty.

Comment: @user2213396: I've asked 25 mins ago: Please show your `try/catch` block.

Comment: @user2213396: Thank you for finally posting your `try/catch` block. I'm pretty sure this question will help you find your error: [Is it a bad idea to use printStackTrace() in Android Exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855187/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-printstacktrace-in-android-exceptions) Follow the advice you find there, and if you still can't fix your program post your logcat (that will provide necessary information) here.

Comment: Post the whole class, not just the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @jlordo Added the whole class in the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `this.db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);`. Because I had the same problem few months ago and that is the solution.

Comment: It is giving an error in compiler when I do what you said: "db cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Answer (score 0):

instead of db.insert() ... use db.insertOrThrow(), probably some constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `db` object? Is it `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();` ? I have seen that some people uses `getReadAbleDatabase()` istead of the `getWriteableDatabase()` method.