# setOnFocusChangeListener is causing crash with edittext

Tags: java, android

Fairly new so sorry for the stupid question..
I'm trying to update the TextView as soon as the EditText loses focus. The Edittext needs to convert to an int to calculate what the textview should show. As soon as the EditText loses focus the app crashes.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText strScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.strScore);
    final TextView strMod = findViewById(R.id.strMod);



        strScore.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View strScoreView, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    updateModifier(strMod,strScore);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void updateModifier(TextView modifier, EditText score){
        int scoreInt = Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString());
        int modifierInt = scoreInt - 10 / 2;
        modifier.setText(modifierInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: _needs to convert to an int_ Probably `NumberFormatException`. Are you getting an exception? If yes, post the details including the stack trace which you can get from the log as explained in this _Stack Overflow_ question: [Is it a bad idea to use printStackTrace() for caugt Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855187/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-printstacktrace-for-caugt-exceptions)

Comment: Share the error

Comment: @HelloWorld Do the change mentioned in GuruCharan answer it will help you fix ur program

Comment: @HelloWorld please post stack trace from logcat next time as mentioned by others in comment

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
modifier.setText(String.valueOf(modifierInt));
```

in  `updateModifier()` method, because you are trying to set Integer value to Textview which accepts only Strings

Comment: the reason the op is getting exception because he is trying to set integer value to textview which is mentioned by this answerer.if the op just makes the change his program will get executed successfully

Comment: that was exactly right, thank you